# How to convert data from the List of strings into a Map<String, Integer> with Stream API?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I tried to convert data from the *list* of strings into a `Map<String, Integer>` with the Stream API.

But the way I did it is not correct:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> converter (List<String> data){
        return data.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e, Function.identity()));
```

If we have `List.of("5", "7", "5", "8", "9", "8")`

***task №1***  as key - `String`, and  value - *character frequency*

***task №2***  as key - `String`, and  value - *string converted to integer*

Comment: What do you want as your key and value?  Your current stream would return `Map<String,String>`.  Note that `e->e` and `Function.identity()` do the same thing.

Comment: If we have List.of("5", "7", ''5", "8", "9,"8") , as key - String, and about value -maybe, character frequency

Comment: "String, and value- converted string to integer"  You realize you lose data doing this right since the key is unique and will overwrite whatever was previously there.  You would only have one `5 = 5` value in your map, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **task №1** as key - String, and value - ***character frequency***

In order to obtain the frequency of every **character**, you need to *flatten* each string in a list (i.e. split every *string* into *characters*).

Since **Java 9** we can use method [`chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) which returns a stream of characters represented with `int` primitives.

`flatMapToInt(String::chars)` will produce an `IntStream`, containing characters from every string in the given list.

Then `mapToObj()` creates a single-character string for every stream element.

To generate the map of frequencies, we can utilize collector `Collectors.groupingBy()`. `Function.identity()` is used as the first argument is an equivalent of `e -> e`, it's just a way to tell that stream elements will be used as a *key* without any changes. The second argument is a *downstream collector* `Collectors.counting()`, that generates the number of elements mapped to a particular *key*.

```
public static Map<String, Long> getCharacterFrequency(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()                               // Stream<String>
            .flatMapToInt(String::chars)               // IntStream
            .mapToObj(ch -> String.valueOf((char) ch)) // String<String>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                           Collectors.counting()));
}
```

> **task №2** as key - String, and value - **string** converted to **integer**

You can do it by using a flavor of *collector* `Collectors.toMap()` that expects three arguments:

- *keyMapper* - a function that produces the *key* from a stream element;
- *valueMapper* - a function that produces the *value* from a stream element;
- *mergeFunction* - a function that determines how to resolve a situation when two values happens to be mapped to the same key.

Although, the *mergeFunction* in the code below is not doing anything special, it needs to be provided, otherwise the first encountered duplicate will cause an `IllegalStateException`.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getStringValuesMappedToInts(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), // key (String)
                                      Integer::valueOf,   // value (Integer)
                                      (v1, v2) -> v1));    // function that resolves collisions
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> source = List.of("5", "7", "57", "59", "5", "8", "99", "9", "8");
    // task 1
    System.out.println("task 1:\n" + getCharacterFrequency(source));
    // task 2
    System.out.println("task 2:\n" + getStringValuesMappedToInts(source));
}
```

**Output**

```
task 1:
{5=4, 7=2, 8=2, 9=4}
task 2:
{99=99, 57=57, 59=59, 5=5, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this for a frequency.  Note that a map can't have duplicate keys.

```
List<String> list2 = List.of("5", "7", "5", "8", "9","8");
```

- the `key` is the `String`.
- the `value` starts a `1`.
- the `Integers::sum` adds `1` for every occurrence.

```
Map<String, Integer> freq = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
         e->e, (a)->1, Integer::sum));

freq.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
5=2
7=1
8=2
9=1
```

for the second task, to convert the strings to `ints` is trivial.  But remember that dups can't exist so they have to be properly merged. This is similar to the first task except instead of counting we're just converting to an integer.  Since you have duplicate integers, you need to provide *instructions* on what to do.  That is the `merge` function `(a,b)->a` which says for existing value `a` and new value `b`, just  keep `a`

```
List<String> list2 = List.of("5", "7", "5", "8", "9","8");
Map<String, Integer> map = list2.stream().collectCollectors.toMap(e->e,
              Integer::valueOf,
              (a,b)->a); // just keep the first one
```

prints

```
5=5
7=7
8=8
9=9
```

Comment: You updated your question so I provide additional information to address the second part.